# iceRestart option in createOffer

Tags: webrtc, openwebrtc

On network reconnection, we are trying to create an offer with a parameter:

```
iceRestart : true
```

But, at the receiver user its throwing an error:

> InvalidStateError: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called in wrong state: kHaveLocalOffer.

Basically, its trying to create a new offer instead of restarting the existing connection. What is the correct way to implement iceRestart in createOffer method?

```
self.constraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] 
initWithMandatoryConstraints:
@[
[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveAudio" 
value:@"true"],
[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveVideo" 
 value:@"true"],
[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"iceRestart" value:@"true"]
] optionalConstraints:nil];
[_peerConnection createOfferWithDelegate:self 
constraints:self.constraints];
```

Answer (score 3):

`InvalidStateError: kHaveLocalOffer` might occur for example when you set remote SDP offer instead of answer after setting local SDP offer in the same `RTCPeerConnection`.

As presented in the diagram below, WebRTC can automatically recover from the `disconnected` state if the network conditions of both peers didn't change. So you should perform ice restart only if the `iceConnectionState` switched to `failed` or if you are sure that your device has switched the network and obtained different IP.

[image]

The simplest way to implement reconnects from `failed` state, is to define that only one peer will do the iceRestart offer, for example, the one who initiated the connection.

Some javascript pseudocode:

```
this.rtcPeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
      if (this.rtcPeerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'failed' && this.isConnectionInitializer) {
          // createOffer({iceRestart: true})
          // set offer as local description
          // send offer to peer
      }
};
```